# Is it possible to test SQL data in a C# unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
public ApplicationLayout Get(string objectName, string userName)
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ApplicationLayout WHERE ObjectName = @ObjectName AND UserName=@UserName";

        return db.Query<ApplicationLayout>(sql, new {ObjectName = objectName, UserName = userName}).FirstOrDefault();
    } 
}
```

I have some code here, and I was wondering if it is possible to perform a unit test in C# using SQL data (any framework). From what I've seen, it is not possible. Can anyone please confirm this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible... a bit more of a detailed answer... as long as your connection string is to a valid database (whether a real DB, an in-memory DB, a lower environment DB, etc.) and the schema which you are querying exists, then yes, a unit test could hit this code with that connection string and get the data back out.

Comment: I might suggest a SQLServer Compact temp database that you setup before the test and then destroy after, it should help portability and consistency

Comment: Short answer is "Yes, but don't".

Comment: short answer is, Yes, but do.   But your sql tests should be part of "Integration Testing"  rather than your unit testing.  For your unit tests mock out the part that talks to the db,  but, your sql often contains a lot of code (unfortunately string based) that needs a test of some sort to ensure it does what you expect

Comment: It is NOT a unit test but an Integration Test. Unless your dB has the same static data, how will you confirm your test passed or failed?

Comment: everyones a little too hung up on it not being a "Unit" test. but really the sql should be unit tested, it's just technically tricky to do so as it's packaged with C# so gets done via integration testing.

Comment: We use local db for that combined with EF's `.CreateDatabase()` but you can also run any migration scripts against that as part of the UT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, but not recommended for a *unit* test.

When you talk about a unit test, you're usually talking about a test that can be repeatably executed in isolation; that is, it has no dependencies outside the code assembly where it lives (and ideally each test should not go very far beyond a single class being tested), and has no lasting side effects regardless of how the test is started or stopped (doesn't require use of the file system, or a database, etc). This is because unit tests, being the smallest and most fine-grained tests, are intended to test the code that you yourself wrote. You didn't write SQL Server, so SQL Server shouldn't be in the scope of a unit test.

Now, once you widen the scope to integration tests and acceptance tests, now you're testing that code you wrote plays nicely with all the external dependencies you didn't write. Integration tests can touch external data, like databases, and can write to as well as read from those external stores, as long as they clean up after themselves properly, either by returning a persistent database to its original condition after the run, or just using a portable DB like SQLite or MSS Express, setting up the necessary schema and test data as part of your test setup, and then just blowing the DB away when it's done.

For many, this is splitting hairs, and unit testing frameworks like MSTest or NUnit don't prevent you using them to create a test that has external dependencies. These are merely good ideas for structuring your full test suite into a fine-grained, fast-running, repeatable component that you can run on any change you make, and the longer-running, wider-scoped proof of correctness that might run overnight.

Comment: he wouldn't be testing sqlserver he would be testing sql he wrote, it can be complicated and it's important that it returns the data you want or mutates the thing you want. ie, sql is code :)

Comment: True, and this is one of the hairs that is commonly split; "hand-coded" SQL that lives at the data layer does have to be tested, but because said SQL lives on the database server, any testing code written to exercise the program's compiled code has to reach out beyond the process boundaries to exercise it, and so that test by definition is not a unit test. This doesn't mean you can't have an *automated* test of that SQL, but it's more correctly a test at the integration level, not the unit level.

Comment: sure, everyones pointing that out, including myself.   However the sql is odd, the sql itself really needs unit testing as well.  just like C# targets the CLR and needs unit testing, the sql targets SQL SERVER and needs fine grained unit tests.   However it gets packaged as part of the C# so falls into integration testing in most scenarios.  I use a separate project (along with schema migrations) to do this kind of "unit" test.

Answer (score 1):

I always did my testing on a dedicated database. You can do a setup and a tear down, and basically recreate the database (or restore it from a backup) each time you run those tests. It is a lot more involved than just plain C# unit testing. Like some comments stated, it's not really unit testing anymore but stuff needs to be tested one way or another.

Comment: your answer should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

The modern approach to orchestrate testing against a real SQL engine has to work:

- locally on dev machines (that run Windows, MacOS or Linux);
- build pipelines in the cloud (e.g. Azure DevOps pipelines, GitHub Actions,
  etc.).

> **TL;DR** – check out [DbSample](https://github.com/AKlaus/DbSample) on GitHub, a sample EF Core based
> project with fully automated tests against MS SQL Server and a GitHub
> Actions pipeline.

A detailed analysis of orchestrating tests is covered in "[Pain & Gain of automated tests against SQL (MS SQL, PostgreSQL)](https://alex-klaus.com/dotnet-sql-tests/)" article. The key steps are:

1. Launch SQL engine in Docker (use official images for [SQL Server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) or [PostgreSQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres))
2. Create a test database and populate the schema, logic, lookup dictionaries, etc (via command line for the containers)
3. Connect xUnit/NUnit tests to the database and for each test (rinse and repeat):

   1. Seed test data
   2. Perform the testable activity and checks
   3. Revert the database to the pristine state (via [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn))
4. Tear down the SQL engine along with the database and other artefacts.

P.S. I know, the OP said "*unit tests*" but perhaps meant a more broad "*automated tests*"